# BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::makeAllSearchable()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am trying to run the command `php artisan scout:import "App\User"` to import user records into search driver as per documentation ([Laravel 5.3 Scout Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scout)). I keep getting [BadMethodCallException]
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::makeAllSearchable()
as an error. Why am I getting this error? I have included the searchable trait in my users controller and added the scout class to my app/config providers array, so I am struggling to see why the method doesn't exist...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not add the trait to the controller but to the model. So in your case to App\User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    use Searchable;
}
```

Comment: I am literally ashamed of myself for not following such simple instructions... Not only that, but why on earth would the searchable trait even be in the controller? Too much time coding in one day. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Like Jakub has said, you have to add the Searchable trait to your User **model**, not to the controller.

If you're using `toSearchableArray()` on your model, do not forget to include the `id` column in the array, otherwise it won't work.

You could also comment the `toSearchableArray()` function, import the existing users and then add it back.